# Django models.py year field

Tags: python, django, field, datefield

I created a database with population and years by IntegerField but is there any way to create the year field by datefield just for years neither months or days?

```py
class Nufus_ilce(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    population = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.city, self.year)
```

Comment: Why do you want to make it a date field ?

Comment: firstly i want to identfy as a date and second i have some trouble shown in html table when USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True is used. @bruno desthuilliers

Comment: USE_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR only affects localized data, and you can control which data are localized and which are not (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#controlling-localization-in-templates). In all cases, changing your db schema only for presentation issues is an antipattern. This leaves is with "firstly i want to identfy as a date", which is a bit of a tautology: "Q : why do you want X ?"  "A: Because I want X" ;-)

Comment: NB: not saying there isn't any (debatably valid) reason to make this field a datefield, just wondering why you would want to do so (which concrete issue you're trying to solve with this change).

Answer (score 2):

Usually models.IntegerField is a good choice for juste a year.
However, if you want to perform some datetime operations, then declare your year as model.DateField and save year 2019 as date(2019, 1, 1).

Answer (score 0):

Well You can continue using `IntegerField` or convert it to `CharField` because we are going to convert that value to string for converting it to python datetime object.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Nufus_ilce(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    year = models.CharField(default='2012')
    population = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.city, self.year)
    @property
    def get_year(self):
        date = timezone.datetime.strptime('%Y', self.year)  # format it to datetime object. You need to convert `year` to str if it is `IntergerField`. ex: str(self.year).
        return date
```

Now you could just use `instance.get_year`.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the DATE datatype used in SQL includes year, month and day. So "1999" does not fit the datatype. In other words, for SQL, it is not a date. If you need it to be a DATE datatype, then use `DateField` and store the data like "1999-01-01" or with the month and day of your choice. If you do not need it to be a DATE datatype, use the `PositiveIntegerField`, which should be just fine for most cases.